# Why should I add Hibernate as a framework to the WAR module?

Tags: jpa, jakarta-ee, netbeans, war

I use NetBeans and I don't understand something. Could somebody explain me why should I add Hibernate as a framework to my WAR module in an Java EE application? The WAR module is just the presentation layer. I will access DB in the EJB module. But there is no way to add it as a framework to there. When I try to drag the jars from the WAR libraries to the EJB libraries the cursor changes to "dropping is disabled" and nothing happens. Why does not take place it in the right place? (E.g. in the case of a multi tiered app)
I just want to access my data as entities in the EJB module.

Comment: If you stick to the standard JPA APIs and you're running on a modern Java EE server then you don't need to worry about Hibernate at all.

Answer (score 0):

A WAR is a Web application archive, which means that it is more than the presentation layer.

In the past the common way was to use EAR files that contained each EJB JARs, library JARs and WARs. The classloader hierarchy then went (most of the time) Server -> EAR -> WAR.

Over the last couple of JavaEE releases the WAR started to take over this responsibility (AFAIK at least in the web profile of JavaEE).

So you add both your EJB-JAR and library JARs to the WAR through WEB-INF/lib. Both artifacts are loaded by the application server and scanned for managed resources, e.g. EJBs or CDI beans.

If you want to put it aside the WAR you have to use an EAR or put Hibernate into your application server's classpath.

Hope that clarifies things.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I know most of this. This is not clarify the case : what about a distributed, multi tier architecture? When the presentation and the business logic take place on different nodes. In this case no reason to deploy Hibernate on the web server. This is a Java EE app, so EAR always exists.